# changing directory related to a github repo

Tags: git, github

I'm transitioning source control from VSS to GIT using github. I've toyed with it a little, made a repo, loaded some code. Now I'm ready to really start setting it up for our codebase and I want to change the directory that the repo points to. I basically want to start over. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change your local directory:

```
git remote set-url [--add] [--push] <name> <newurl>
```

Obviously, --add will add a url, and --push will push to it.

If you want to change the repository as it is on github, you'll have to create a new one and copy your repository across.

Comment: I ended up just deleting it on github and starting over. I couldn't get things to sync up using anything else I read.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already created the remote repository then simply navigate to the directory you want to create the local repository in and do a git clone.

```
git clone git://github.com/foo/bar.git
```

Check out [these](http://gitref.org/creating/) instructions on how to set up a fresh git repository.

If you need to hook up your local repository to the one on the server then:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:foo/bar.git
git push origin master
```

Do something like the above.